# Неожиданное поведение preg_replace()

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть задача удалить из текста последний перевод строки `\n`, если за ним нет символов, либо его же и пробелы следующие за ним, если кроме пробелов до конца текста нет других символов.

Использую [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) и регулярное выражение `%\n\x20*$%`

Тест выдающий ожидаемое поведение при замене:

```
$text = "abcd\n     \n     ";
var_dump(preg_replace('%\n\x20*$%', '', $text, -1, $count), $count);
var_dump(preg_replace('%\n\x20*$%', '', $text, 1, $count), $count);
```

Результат работы:

```
string 'abcd
     ' (length=10)
int 1

string 'abcd
     ' (length=10)
int 1
```

Тест выдающий неожиданный результат:

```
$text = "abcd\n     \n";
var_dump(preg_replace('%\n\x20*$%', '', $text, -1, $count), $count);
var_dump(preg_replace('%\n\x20*$%', '', $text, 1, $count), $count);
```

Результат работы:

```
string 'abcd' (length=4) <== замена прошла два раза, 
int 2                    <== вместо одного как ожидалось 

string 'abcd
' (length=5)             <== "съежены" пробелы до символа перевода строки,
int 1                    <== даже при выполнении всего 1ой замены
```

**Вопрос**: В чем моя ошибка?

**P.S.** Аналогичное регулярное выражение для начала текста работает как ожидалось во всех случаях.

Comment: Может вам вообще rtrim нужен, а не регулярка?

Comment: @Мелкий, у `rtrim()` нет ограничения на количество срабатываний.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> По умолчанию, PCRE обрабатывает данные как однострочную символьную
>   строку (даже если она содержит несколько разделителей строк).
>   Метасимвол начала строки '^' соответствует только началу
>   обрабатываемого текста, в то время как метасимвол "конец строки" '$'
>   соответствует концу текста, либо позиции перед завершающим текст
>   переводом строки (в случае, если модификатор D не установлен).

Т.е. `$` трактуется как конец строки **ПЕРЕД** `\n`, если он является последним символом.

В вашем случае надо использовать модификатор `D`

```
$text = "abcd\n     \n";
var_dump(preg_replace('%\n\x20*$%D', '', $text, -1, $count), $count);
var_dump(preg_replace('%\n\x20*$%D', '', $text, 1, $count), $count);

string(10) "abcd
     "
int(1)
string(10) "abcd
     "
int(1)
```